# Feed request Ip

Tags: security, newsfeed, pages, network

In one of our Office365 Sharepoint pages, we are consuming a RSS Feed. The feed provider filters out the requests from unknown IP's. 
It looks like the Request IP occasionally changes, so the feed stops working. 
Is there any way to keep this IP static or to have a list of all the IP's used by Office365? In this last case, I suppose it depends on the region of deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online is a shared environment and hence using the IP Address may not be the ideal solution.

I would recommend using the FQDN like `*.tenant.sharepoint.com`